# Unit tests isolation with jestjs

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

What is the best way to handle test isolation with jest? I want to test an ES6 class with static methods and mock the methods not directly concerned by the unit test.

My class file :

```
class Util {

    static getFirstName() {
        return "John";
    }

    static getLastName() {
        return "Doe";
    }

    static getFullName(){
        return `${Util.getFirstName()} ${Util.getLastName()}`;
    }
}
```

My test file :

```
import Util from '../src/util';

test("Test getFullName", () => {
    Util.getFirstName = jest.fn().mockReturnValue("MockFirstName");
    Util.getLastName = jest.fn().mockReturnValue("MockLastName");

    expect(Util.getFullName()).toBe("MockFirstName MockLastName")
});

test("Test getFirstName", () => {
    expect(Util.getFirstName()).toBe("John")
});

test("Test getLastName", () => {
    expect(Util.getLastName()).toBe("Doe")
});
```

This way, my two last tests will fail because the mocks set on the first test are still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming those `import` statements are being transpiled to `require`, you should be able to use [resetModules](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestresetmodules):

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Clears the require cache so that a new module is require'd
    // before each test.
    jest.resetModules();
});
```

Then in each test, you'll need to require the module:

```
test("name", () => {
    const { default: Util } = require("../src/util");
});
```

Or if you can use dynamic import syntax:

```
test("name", () => import("../src/util")
    .then(({ default: Util }) => {
        expect(Util.getFirstName()).toBe("John");
    })
);
```

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't know this method! But in this case I need to re-import my module in the beforeEach, right?

Comment: @AtomeDev Yes, sorry that should be part of the answer